# MySQLi Prepared statements and fetching fields

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have an array of strings called `$lines` and I want to search a database with each string.

What I have that works:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $line = real_escape_string($line);
    $sql = "select * from $table where $column like '%$line%'"
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            //Name and Date are are only 2 out of 15+ column names from the db table
            echo "<tr><td> {$row['Name']} </td>
                  <td>     {$row['Date']} </td></tr>"; 
    }
```

However, I don't want this. I want to use prepared statements and be able to use column names like above. What I've tried: (from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php))

```
$vars = array();
$data = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `$column` LIKE '%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $line);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->store_result();
$meta = $result->result_metadata();

echo "WORKS"; //doesn't print
while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    $vars[] = &$data[$field->name];
call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_result'), $vars);
$i = 0;
while ($result->fetch())  {
    $array[$i] = array();
        foreach ($data as $k=>$v)
            $array[$i][$k] = $v;
        $i++;
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

As using prepared statements bypasses the need for quotes and passes in the exact variable, you need to pass the wildcards in on your variable, not in the query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `$column` LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", '%'.$line.'%');
```

Comment: Ok thanks. However my echo statement is still not being printed

Comment: Are you not getting any rows at all, or just those columns? If it's just those columns, try `var_dump($row);` to find out what exactly is in that array.